# What type of dark matter candidate does the Madala particle predict if any?

Tags: particle-physics, dark-matter

The [Madala particle](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=madala+boson) has been theorized as the boson that may give dark matter its mass.  I have read a few articles in the press on this new hypothetical particle but must admit I am a little confused. Hoping for some particle physics readers out there. Correct me if I am wrong but I assume the Madala particle is assumed to give dark matter it's mass?  So what happens if the dark matter turns out to be something like primordial black holes or maybe axions? Does the mandala boson require a specific kind of dark matter?  The other confusion on my part is that the articles I am reading seem to me to imply that since it  is not predicted by the Standard Model then it would require a new "fundamental force"? At his point since the Standard Model is essentially complete as far as its predictive powers go ( another perhaps bad assumption on my part ) will any new found boson at the LHC imply an associated new fundamental force, if so then wouldn't the super symmetric particles if ever found also bear a new fundamental force?

Comment: I assume you mean Mandela particle. Have not seen anything on it since 1975. If it's anything more recent can you provide a link? If you meant mandala, don't see anything physics

Comment: @Bob Bee  this refers to the "Madala boson"

Comment: The edits have only served to make this question confusing. It originally said "Mandala" and gives a description consistent with the "Madala boson", which seems a bit crank-ish to say the least https://www.wits.ac.za/news/latest-news/research-news/2016/2016-09/wits-scientists-predict-the-existence-of-a-new-boson-.html

Comment: You will find the source Bruce Mellado HEP group LHC.   I don't think he's a crank but on the other hand you may know best.  Article posted on Sep 13. 2016. from  www.hngn.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will copy a comment by Lubos Motl  on this :

> [Off-topic: Some news](http://motls.blogspot.gr/2016/09/chen-ning-yang-against-chinese-colliders.html) reports talk about a new "Madala boson". It seems to be all about this [2-weeks-old 5-page-long hep-ph](http://arxiv.org/abs/1608.03466) preprint presenting a two-Higgs-doublet model that also claims to say something about the composition of dark matter (which is said to be composed of a new scalar χ). I've seen many two-Higgs-doublet papers and papers about dark matter and I don't see a sense in which this paper is more important or more persuasive.

from the linked paper:

> The confirmation of the Higgs boson in Run I data at the Large Hadron Collider (LHC) and the excesses in recent Run II data suggest scenarios beyond the Standard Model (SM). We pursue a study in a minimal model which is an extension of a scalar doublet in the SM known as two-Higgs doublet model (THDM). Following earlier suggestions two real scalars χ and S have been introduced in the THDM where χ is treated as a candidate for dark matter.

It starts with [this 2015 phenomenological](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.00612) analysis which claims a 3 sigma new Higgs like peak at 272GeV.

So it is about an extension to the standard model with a more complicated Higgs sector that provides an x particle that might give rise to  dark matter ( matter interacting mainly gravitationally). That dark matter consists of elementary particles from an extension of the standard model is *one of the scenarios* in trying to explain it. If this x exists and is measured experimentally, it becomes a good candidate for the case.

3 sigma do not a discovery make.

There are other proposals for dark matter candidates and those also have to be tested by experiment and observations. It is an open field of research.

Comment: There exists an author by the name of Mandal in the 2015 paper, and it is maybe a coincidence that "madala" and "mandala" sound similar, or  it might be the first fellow who drew attention to the 272 GeV possible excess.

Comment: The article I refer to appears yesterday and sits Bruce Mellado as the source.  He is with the HEP group of the LHC.  The article is written Sep. 13 2016.  There seems to be a lot of confusion about my question. Next time I will be more careful and include link to the article, that would have helped.   However the posted  answer is enlightening and I will accept it.

Comment: Your reference is a popularization of  the arxiv publication  that I give in the "two weeks old" reference. The Madala (or Mandala) identity  was made with the 2015 publication given as a last link . Both publications have among the authors Mellado.

Comment: @Anna Thanks for clarifying this. Do you happen to know if there is any more information from LHC on their plans for collecting more data, or additional channels, for the 272GeV excess? I agree with you 3 sigma is far off, and I'd heard about it but not followed it for a while. Do you know if the arXiv publication you refer to (I just read) is proposing any channels that were not collected before? If not it seems like theorizing something not yet found, without predicting anything new the LHC should look for, or anyone else? Just wondering, don't research it just because of my question.

Comment: @BobBee There are 6000 physicists looking at the LHC data, a large percentage of this graduate students (~25%) trying to dig out something "new" and "unexpected" for their thesis. If they do get it, we will for sure hear about it.  They are looking for channels from all possible predictions. Nothing came up at the recent conferences. I expect we shall hear about it if they do hit on something. They are still running.